# Clients from multiple subnets can't simultaneously connect to server

Tags: networking, connection, subnet, network-interface

I have setup servers for several games in the past where either players from outside my local network could join, or players from within my local network could join, but not both at the same time.  Which ever joined first would block the other.  Both local and "remote" (Internet) connections are to the same network interface on the server host.  Other players of the same "type" (local or Internet) as the first to join are able to connect, but none from the other "type".  If all of those players disconnect, then the players of the other "type" that were previously unable to connect will be able to connect.

*I'm deliberately omitting the names of the specific games because I'm not asking about those games.  If it turns out that the game software is the cause, then so be it.  This question is about potential networking issues that may be the cause.*

- Is there an explanation for why the network would behave this way?
- If this is a networking issue, is there a fix or workaround?
- If this is a software/server issue, is there an explanation for how it could be causing this kind of network behavior?  And is there any kind of workaround that isn't too invasive, something that doesn't require topology changes?  Perhaps some kind of tunneling/forwarding to "trick" the server?

**Details**

*DISCLAIMER*: I am not a network expert.
I have two NAT routers "chained". I think of them as "inner" and "outer". Each run DHCP, creating two subnets. (192.168.1-2.x) *Note that there are no known issues with the network as is.  Everyone can reach the Internet and all addresses/services I would expect them to.*

[image: network]

The servers usually live behind the inner router. The local users are behind the outer router and connect via port forwarding (they are on a different subnet from the server). Remote/Internet users get through the outer router also via port forwarding.  *Again note that each scenario works independently.  It's just when both remote and "local" clients try to connect at the same time where someone gets blocked.*

What makes this extra strange (and perhaps points to the software as the culprit) is that the local and remote connections, since they are both being forwarded from a different subnet, should appear identical to the server if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Is the server on the same network as the local users?  How are remote users getting in - is it via port forwarding?

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: My answer needs revision based on your graphic.  Is your "Inner" router's LAN IP address (the one facing the game server and Client A) 192.168.2.10? If YES, what is it's IP on the "Outer router's" subnet (it's WAN/Internet interface IP address)?

Comment: Ah, shoot! My diagram is inconsistent. The inner router's WAN IP is 192.168.2.10.  Its LAN IP is 192.168.1.1.

Comment: No worries.  That makes good sense now.  Two questions: 1) Can *Client A*, being on the same subnet as the game server, connect to it at the same time a user from the Internet connects?  2) Have you tried for testing purposes moving the Game Server to the `192.168.2.1/24` subnet?

Comment: I believe that I have tried both of those, but unfortunately I do not clearly recall the results of either.  I *believe* that I had the same contention issue with Internet clients while on Client A.

Comment: If you have the same issue with Internet clients and Client A (which is not getting its traffic routed/NATed/forwarded in any way), then your problem is the game/game server.  Again, if you move the game server to the "Outer" router's LAN subnet and still have the problem, the game server is at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Double NAT-ing is your problem.**

Your configuration *should* work, but it's not surprising that you're having issues.  True routers would work in your setup just fine, but NAT gateway "routers" when stacked one behind the other can introduce a variety of unwanted behavior.

It's reasonable to want an explanation for this, but in a case where the configuration "should" work, the explanation would be found in how each router is implementing NAT and/or port forwarding, something even the device's user guide won't provide sufficient technical details about.

If you move the game server to a subnet behind a single Internet-facing router/gateway your problems should disappear.

Comment: If double-port forwarding is the problem, then why does it work, ever?  The issue I described only occurs with some servers.  With some servers, both local and remote clients are able to connect at the same time.  Even for servers that have this issue, the double-NAT clients are able to connect, it just prevents the local clients from connecting (and vice versa).  If double-NATing is causing the issue, then please explain how it is doing so.

Comment: It is probably a bug in the NAT implementation.  What are the differences between those that do and don't?  The best bet would be to not NAT on the inner router and just static route the subnet from outer router.  This is a fix, not an answer.

Comment: I setup a new server behind the outer router and put a dedicated CS:Source server on it.  Was able to connect from Client A, the laptop on the 192.168.2.x subnet, and from an Internet client.  This is one of the servers that gave me problems before when it was behind the inner router.  "Buggy NAT implementation" strikes me as rather implausible, but so far that's the only explanation.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things where you have to see it happen over and over before you concede that what *should* work rarely does.